# How to access Jenkinsfile parameters values as strings in a loop

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, gstring

In our Jenkinsfile  we have a lot of parameters (parameterized build) and in this case I want to check if each parameter is toggled and act on that. These parameters have similar names but end with a different decimal, so I would like to iterate over them to achieve this.

I have something like:

```
if ("${TEST_00}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[0]) }
if ("${TEST_01}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[1]) }
if ("${TEST_02}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[2]) }
if ("${TEST_03}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[3]) }
if ("${TEST_04}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[4]) }
if ("${TEST_05}" == "true") { testTasksToRun.add(testsList[5]) }
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<testsList.size(); i++) {
    if ("${TEST_0${i}}" == "true") {
        testTasksToRun.add(testsList[i])
    }
}
```

I tried to search for solutions and experimented on the GroovyConsole but didn't manage to get anything to work. Looks like it has something to do with "binding", but I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`params` is a `GlobalVariable` that when accessed returns an unmodifiable map. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/2ed7a0d13ae832292b8b849818e1645b0aaec2f3/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/ParamsVariable.java#L50-L81).

Because it returns a `Map`, you can use the same strategies to iterate over it as you would for normal Groovy maps.

```groovy
params.each { key, value ->
  // do things
}
```

```groovy
for (entry in params) {
  // entry.key or entry.value
}
```

Newer versions of the Groovy CPS libraries should handle most iteration cases since [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481) has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you mkobit! Using `params["TEST_0${i}"]` worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the this keyword, and reference properties of the current scope. The below sample code works in the Groovy Console (as this is a script, the @Field annotation is necessary, for scoping)

```
import groovy.transform.Field

def testsList = ['a','b','c']

@Field 
def TEST_00 = "true"

@Field 
def TEST_01 = "false"

@Field 
def TEST_02 = "true"

for(int i=0; i<testsList.size(); i++) {
    if ( this."TEST_0${i}" == "true") {
        println testsList[i]
    }
}
```

In a Jenkins pipeline script, you can do something along the lines of:

```
node {
    def testsList = ['a','b','c']

    def myInput = input message: 'Give me input 1', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'DEMO1'), string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'DEMO2'), string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'DEMO3')]

    for(int i=0; i<testsList.size(); i++) {
        if ( myInput."DEMO${i+1}" == "true") {
           println testsList[i]
        }
    }
}
```

When prompted, it will output only the values (a,b,c) where you supply the string "true" to the input

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I will give it a try soon! Sadly I think it will not work because the parameters are injected by a Jenkins plugin, so I guess it's not using that @Field annotation...

Comment: The @Field annotation I don't think you need in Jenkins, it takes care of that for you. I used it just to get it to run as a Script in the Groovy Console. Admittedly, I have not tested this in Jenkins.

Comment: I've added a Jenkins script demoing something similar to what you are trying to

Comment: I think I couldn't save the parameters like that because they are added with `properties([parameters([string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'master')])])`, but as mkobit posted on his answer all of the params are accessible in `params[]`! :)